# Is it possible to create your own unique Ubuntu image?

Tags: system-installation, themes

I have very limited knowledge about OS installation and this side of computing however I was just wondering:

Instead of installing Ubuntu 18.04 and then having to install my preferred themes and apps etc, is it possible to create an installation image that installs my preferences that I can configure somewhere?

If so, what is this called and where could I learn about it?

Are there disadvantages associated with this?

Comment: Do you mean something like Opensuse Studio? (where you your packages & it'll create your own ISO including minor name changes etc). Main Ubuntu allows for OEM installs though it's not what you're after.  There are also scripts that will 'spin' and ISO of your installed system (allowing custom installs of what you've got installed on other machines).  Please note Ubuntu releases are generally *yy.mm* in format, ie. 18.04 for 2018.April LTS release, 18.10 for 2018.October release, though Ubuntu Core 18 (*year only*) is a different IoT system build for 2018.  You should be specific as to which.

Comment: Opensuse or a 'spin' script sound exactly what I am trying to explain!  I will have to look into them further.

I did not know about that release format, thanks!